# Change EF Core Migrations to different default owner

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating a new .NET Core 3.1.3 application, connecting to a new SQL Server 2016 database. The connection is a trusted connection. The EF migration tool is creating the tables with me as the owner.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialDb
dotnet ef database update
```

I don't want that. I want the tables to be owned by a service id that we have created for the purpose. What is the safest and most efficient way to default table creation to that owner?

Comment: Don' use a trusted connection. Log in with the service id..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a schema for your Entities, EF will generate the DDL with no schema specified.  And in SQL Server this means that the object will be created in the user's default schema.  Normally the user's default schema should be `dbo`, but if it's not, then the object will be created in a different schema.

And in SQL Server objects are owned (again by default) by the owner of the schema in which they are created.

So, configure the tables to be created in the `dbo` schema, or configure your user's default schema to be `dbo`, and the objects will be created in the `dbo` schema and owned by `dbo`.

eg in OnModelCreating, add

```
foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    et.SetSchema("dbo");
}
```

or in SQL

```
alter user [yourdomain\youruser] with default_schema=dbo
```

Note that if you are the database owner, or a sysadmin, you always connect to the database as `dbo`, and your unqualified DDL will create objects in the `dbo` schema.

> I want the tables to be owned by a service id

You don't normally want objects owned by the identity that the application uses to connect, as that identity should be in a role with least-privileges.  EG no ability to drop tables or create triggers.  Typically the objects should simply be owned by `dbo`.

Comment: Thank you.  That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

At least as of EF Core 6 you can be more succinct with

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
```

Note that if you are using the built-in history table you will need to place extra code in the `onConfiguring`.  Something like

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", "dbo"));
```